# UFT/QTP- Unable to Drag n Drop an image from windows explorer(Windows 7) to the application on browser

Tags: windows-7, drag-and-drop, hp-uft

I have a scenario where I need to Drag N Drop an image file which is on the local hard drive using UFT 12. My application is web application and I'm using Google chrome browser. 
I tried the following things to achieve this but not able to do. I may need your help to perform this talk. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Window("Pictures").WinObject("Items View").WinList("Items View").Select(0).Drag
   Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebElement("DropHere").Drop x,y
2. Window("Pictures").WinObject("Items View").WinList("Items View").Select(0)

   x= Window("Pictures").WinObject("Items View").WinList("Items View").GetROProperty("abs_x")

   y= Window("Pictures").WinObject("Items View").WinList("Items View").GetROProperty("abs_y")

   a= Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebElement("DropHere").GetROProperty("abs_x")

   b= Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebElement("DropHere").GetROProperty("abs_y")

   Set dr = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")

   dr.DragAndDrop x+50, y+50, a+500, b+500, 0
3. Tried analog recording and found it is not good in this case..

I'm surpriced that DeviceReplay also didnt work here. So I suspected It might be Windows7 which is blocking Drag N Drop permission. Later on with little research I came across Windows Integrity level which actually blocks the special permission. So Even I changed the folder and application integrity level(http://www.minasi.com/apps/). This also failed.
Any workaround for this?

Comment: Can someone spend little time to fix it for me please..

Answer (score 1):

Replace: dr.DragAndDrop x+50, y+50, a+500, b+500, 0

by :

```
dr.MouseDown x+50, y+50,0
Wait(1)
dr.MouseDown a+500, b+500, 0
Wait(1)
dr.MouseUp a+500, b+500, 0
```

Issue is on the time to have the **Copy here** label in Chrome before performing the Drop(need to have a focus on the target object: 1 second).

Comment: Nothing worked for me. Finally I went ahead with Sikuli. Created a test to drag and drop and i made it reusable. whenever i need to drag n drop. I'm calling this function. Its little dirty way but. I had no other options. All other ways failed in this case. I wonder how Sikuli has got the controls so easily and the HP product UFT couldn't do the very basic stuff like drag and drop. I feel HP need to concentrate on scenarios like this and need to come up with better solutions..

Comment: I think HP UFT doesn't support drag and drop files to application. I tried making test script like this, the mouse only moves but doesn't even 'carry' the file.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same code as suggested by @Nicolas T, however for me it worked perfectly when i used **abs_x** and **abs_y**, rather than just **x** & **y** properties

Comment: Hey I'm using *abs_x* only u can see that in my code. x, y are just variables.. Are you on Win 7??

Answer (score 1):

It is too late, but see the link below. It features a subroutine that can drag and drop items from windows explorer to the application under test.

[Drag and drop item from windows explorer to application using UFT](http://www.aneejian.com/drag-and-drop-item-from-windows-explorer-to-application-using-uft/)

[Alternate Link](https://gist.github.com/aneejian/3e64945b513458a1e6d210b3b13c801f)

Comment: Me too late here. The link you shared doesn't exist anymore :-(

Comment: Can you please share some other link to get the info please.. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @HarishaKP Check it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I appreciate it. I will have a check today.